# Trends in multiple entries for field per unique ID

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am wanting to see if a customer having completed a certain course influences the other courses they have completed.

Data example:

| Users ID | Course ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | D |

Ideally, I would like to filter on a course ID and have it return a count of other course IDs that users have taken.

E.g. if I filtered on Course A, it would show

| CourseID | Count |
| --- | --- |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 1 |

B count 1, C count 1 and D count 1 because user ID 1 completed B and C on top of course A and ID 3 completed course D on top of A.

I have tried using filters on table visuals, but it either does not work or does not load as the data set is too large.

When I use classic pivots, it just filters to only one course, not courses users also completed.

I’m hoping there’s a simple dax query for this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate table for your slicer since it isn't possible to show rows outside of what is sliced/filtered of the same table.

Create a new Calculated Table with:

```
Course = DISTINCT('YourTable'[Course ID])
```

Use this for your slicer.

Next, create a Measure similar to this one:

```
Users also completed = 
  var slicedCourses = DISTINCT('Course'[Course ID])
  var courseUsers = 
    SUMMARIZE(
      FILTER(ALL('YourTable'), 'YourTable'[Course ID] IN slicedCourses),
      [Users ID],
      "courseCount", DISTINCTCOUNT([Course ID])
    )
  var users = 
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
      FILTER(courseUsers, [courseCount] = COUNTROWS(slicedCourses) ),
      "Users ID", [Users ID]
    )
  var result =
    CALCULATE(
      DISTINCTCOUNT('YourTable'[Users ID]),
      FILTER(
        'YourTable',
        'YourTable'[Users ID] IN users &&
        NOT 'YourTable'[Course ID] IN slicedCourses
      )
    )
  return result
```

In your visual, ensure you are using `'YourTable'[Course ID]` together with the above measure.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much - this worked perfectly. One slight issue, is it doesn't work if i were to select say 'A' and 'B', it simply appends the results to the table. Is there a way to tweek the DAX formula to work for multiple selections on the slicer?

Comment: It should work for multiple selections... see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSMgT.png

Comment: The totals I get at the bottom seem to increase if I select more than one … hmm. On the slicer I have the CourseID from the calculated table is that correct ?

Comment: Just looking at the image actually - if I selected A and B - i would want it to show only C as only user 1 did A and B together. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Tweaked the answer above.